# WSGI Configuration failing on pythonanywhere due to module not being found

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I am currently trying to deploy my python/flask app to pythonanywhere, but am currently stuck on the WSGI Configuration step. Here is my code:

```
import sys
#
## The "/home/azanbade" below specifies your home
## directory -- the rest should be the directory you uploaded your Flask
## code to underneath the home directory.  So if you just ran
## "git clone git@github.com/myusername/myproject.git"
## ...or uploaded files to the directory "myproject", then you should
## specify "/home/azanbade/myproject"
path = '/home/azanbade/path/to/Word-finder'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
#
from app import app as application  # noqa
#
# NB -- many Flask guides suggest you use a file called run.py; that's
# not necessary on PythonAnywhere.  And you should make sure your code
# does *not* invoke the flask development server with app.run(), as it
# will prevent your wsgi file from working.
```

Everything looks fine to me until I try running the app. I continue to get this error message, "**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'**"

Here is a photo of my root directory as well as server(which is my application's main file):
[Root Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NliFG.png), [Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiVPe.png)

Is my configuration formatted correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure the `path` points to the right path to your application.

```
path = '/home/<your-username>/<path-to-your-app-folder>'
```